# Mysql is returning empty result when i use not in (column_name)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am executing 
`select * from tbl_test where 2 in (c1)`

It should return the row but still it's return empty row and when i use 
 `select * from tbl_test where 2 in  (1,2,3)` 
mysql returns a row .

```
 c2 | c3 | c4 |  c1
----+----+----+------
 1  | 3  | 4  | 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a major confusion.  You are confusing a string with 5 characters with a list of 3 integers.  These two things are simply different.  Don't confuse them.

This confusion has then led you (or someone else) to store a list in a single column.  In a relationship database, a column should represent a single value, not a list.  SQL has this really great way of implementing lists.  It is called a *table*.

In MySQL, you can do what you want using `find_in_set()`:

```
select *
from tbl_test
where find_in_set(2, col3) > 0;
```

However, the *right* solution is to fix your data model to have an additional table for the lists.  Such a table would have a column for the `id` in your table and for each value in `col3` -- three rows for your example row.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select * from tbl_test where locate(concat(',',2,',') ,concat(',',c1,','))>0
```